# Video Playing in Background while form has been hidden

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on project in which I have a lot of videos on each form. When I click on button Next to goto next video. the previous form on which my video held hidden but still on playing mode.here is my code

```
 private void tsbNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //tsbPrevious.Visible = true;
        if (fVedio1.Visible == true)
        {
            fVideo1.Hide();//it hide the form on which video is on playing mode

            btnVideo2_Click(sender, e);//it let me go to next form
        }
```

}
what am I doing wrong? I can use fVideo1.Close() but it will not be able any more to start that video again.

Comment: What is fVideo defined as? Does it have a way to pause/stop the video if Hide() doesn't include those options?

Comment: actually I have One main form and other form are inherited from main form so button Next is on Main form and video is on inherited form

Comment: What type of object is Video?

Comment: @Quintium using videolan vlc plugin v2

Comment: I'm not familiar with that control, but sounds like you should check their documentations on how to stop or pause a video instead of expecting Hide() to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
if (fVedio1.Visible == true)
{
    fVideo1.Hide();//it hide the form on which video is on playing mode
    fVideo1.Pause();//it will pause the Video
}
```

And add this to your btnVideo2_Click method:

```
fVideo1.Continue()
```